# Qt6 Docker Ubuntu22.04 CMake Failed to find Qt component "Widgets"

Tags: c++, docker, qt, ubuntu, cmake

I'm trying to build a small Qt6 application on a Docker container. It is running on `Ubuntu:22.04`. I have installed the `qt6-base-dev` package. Here is my small test app:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;
    widget.setFixedSize(400, 400);

    QString helloString = "Hello from " + qgetenv("USER") + "!";
    widget.setWindowTitle(helloString);

    widget.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

And here is my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(testproj)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

add_executable(testproj main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testproj PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

But when my cmake is configuring this error appear:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt component "Widgets".

  Expected Config file at
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake" exists
```

The `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake` is existing.

I couldn't find anything online about this problem.

Comment: Probably, parsing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake` gives its own reasons why this package is discarded. You could try to add to your `CMakeLists.txt` a line `find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED PATHS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Widgets)` and check what CMake will print about that.

Comment: Well new errors has appeared, here is it : https://pastebin.com/nES0y1RQ

Comment: My bad : https://pastebin.com/RFdBbKqd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglvnd-dev` and it worked perfectly !

Comment: Yep that sure did work. But how should any of us have known that!?